# Correct promise chaining

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I am working on a Chrome extension where I need to contact from the page extension code with background script using Chrome messages. This adds a fair level asynch fiddling to my code. The general purpose is to process text macros ie parse text, using data stored in the database accessible from the background script.

at some point, I have:

```
findMacro(key)
.then(result => {
   processMacro(key, result);
}};
```

The processor roughly looks like:

```
function processMacro(shortcut, text) {
  text = macroBuilder(text);
}
```

`macroBuilder` function processes various types of macros, pushing processed text to an array then running join(''). My problem is that, I need to support nested macros and when there are such macros, I call `findMacro` again, which inside does chrome sendMessage to the background process. The processor does something like:

```
function macroBuilder(text) {
  let pieces = [];
  macroProcessorCode(text).forEach(res => {
    res.visit({
      text(txt, ctx) {
        pieces.push(txt);
      },
      dates(obj, ctx) {
        pieces.push(processDates(obj))
      },
      ...
      nested(obj,ctx) {
        let fragments = [];
        fragments.push(
          findMacro(obj.name)
          .then(res => {
            return macroBuilder(res);
          })
        );
        console.log('promised results:', fragments);
        Promise.all(fragments)
        .then(fragments => {
          console.log('resolved results:', fragments);
          pieces.push(fragments);
        });
      }
    });
  });
  return pieces.join('');
}
```

For some reason my function returns before resolving, so `promised results` happens before it returns, and `resolved results` after. In short, I return from the code processing text with the result, before nested macros are processed. This only happens with nested, other types of macros are processed correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: well ... `nested(obj,ctx)` doesn't return anything and `fragments` in there will only ever have one element pushed on to the array anyway, so why do that? (unless this `nested` *macro* (what?) does magicks of course) - what are **nested macros**?

Comment: `console.log('promised results:', fragments);` will happen straight after `fragments.push` because you're pushing a promise, and logging it ... you never wait for that promise to resolve

Comment: `text = macroBuilder(text);` this will never do what you want, as macroBuilder has asynchronous code, therefore can not return a synchronous result (promises don't make asynchronous code synchronous, a common misconception about promises)

Comment: Good points. What do I do?

Comment: @JaromandaX, the fragments.push is actually correct as it is handled with a Promise.all, but, it still needs return...

Comment: as you've not shown what `nested` or `macroProcessorCode` does, it's a bit difficult - step 1: understand promises, the only way to "get at" the resolved value is either using `.then` or async/await

Comment: but you are saying that `romised results happens before it returns` - I assumed you meant that the log output is happening before the `return macroBuilder(res);` - which it will

Comment: return Promise.all(...) => this makes javascript 'wait' for the outcome of the Promise, else you store the Promise.All(...) object into your res.visit

Comment: @Schuere where would `return` go, in my case. Not inside `push`?

Comment: see the above :-)  
return Promise.all(...)

Comment: `return Promise.all` does not do anything different than no `return` ;(. let me think about storing something in `res.visit`. could be a good idea, even though i don't understand how that would work. thank you for your input. it is all helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`macroBuilder` creates a bunch of promises but never does anything with them. Instead, it needs to wait for them and return its own promise that will resolve/reject based on the promises for the pieces/fragments.

This is somewhat off-the-cuff and probably needs tweaking, but should get you going the right direction. See `***` comments:

```
function macroBuilder(text) {
    // *** An array for all the promises below
    const piecePromises = [];
    macroProcessorCode(text).forEach(res => {
        res.visit({
            text(txt, ctx) {
                pieces.push(txt);
            },
            dates(obj, ctx) {
                pieces.push(processDates(obj))
            },
            //...
            nested(obj, ctx) {
                let fragments = [];
                fragments.push(
                    findMacro(obj.name)
                    .then(res => macroBuilder) // *** Note we can just pass `macroBuilder` directly
                );
                console.log('promised results:', fragments);
                // *** Add this promise to the array
                pieces.push(Promise.all(fragments)
                    // (*** This whole then handler can be removed
                    // once you don't need the logging anymore;
                    // just push the result of Promise.all)
                    .then(fragments => {
                        console.log('resolved results:', fragments);
                        return fragments;
                    })
                );
            }
        });
    });
    // *** Wait for all of those and then join; ultimate result
    // is a promise that resolves with the pieces joined together
    return Promise.all(piecePromises).then(pieces => pieces.join(''));
}
```

At that point, there's not much point to `processMacro`; it would just look like this (note that it returns a promise):

```
function processMacro(shortcut, text) {
  return macroBuilder(text);
}
```

...unless there's something you do with `shortcut` that you haven't shown.

Assuming you need `processMacro`, you'd call it like this if you're propagating the promise to the caller:

```
return findMacro(key)
.then(result => processMacro(key, result));
```

...or like this if you're not propagating the promise:

```
findMacro(key)
.then(result => processMacro(key, result))
.catch(err => {
   // Deal with the fact an error occurred
});
```

Since one of the rules of promises is that you either propagate the promise or handle errors from it.

Comment: *(If you don't see "This is somewhat off-the-cuff and probably needs tweaking" above, hit refresh.)*

Comment: Thank you. Did not understand your answer fully, yet. However, this, in general, feels like the right way to go and like perhaps there is no way around your approach for a browser either. Will follow-up later, probably. Appreciate your help, very much.